# Uninstall default-jdk

Tags: apt, uninstall, openjdk

I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install. I did a `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`. Result:

```
java --version
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, mixed mode)
```

Now I did `sudo apt-get purge default-jdk`. Result:

```
java --version
openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, mixed mode)
```

Why is OpenJDK still there?

Answer (score 7):

`default-jdk` in 18.04 has the following description:

```
Description: Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
 This dependency package points to the Java runtime, or Java compatible
 development kit recommended for this architecture, which is
 openjdk-11-jdk for amd64.
```

The results of `apt-cache depends default-jdk` are as follows:

```
default-jdk
  Depends: default-jre
  Depends: default-jdk-headless
  Depends: openjdk-11-jdk
```

The results of `apt-cache rdepends default-jdk` show that openjdk-11-jdk does not depend on *default-jdk*. *default-jdk* points to a Java runtime or Java compatible development kit, but uninstalling *default-jdk* does not uninstall either of these packages.

To remove the packages installed by *default-jdk*, run the following command:

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jdk
```

Comment: Since `default-jdk` depends on `openjdk-11-jdk`, then wouldn't removing `default-jdk` followed by a `sudo apt-get autoremove` accomplish the same?

Comment: @AndroidDev I replied to your comment by editing my answer. My reply is in the 5th paragraph.

Comment: After `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` I use `apt list --installed | grep openj` to see that the packages openjdk-11-jre-headless, openjdk-11-jre, openjdk-11-jdk-headless and openjdk-11-jdk are installed. I use `apt list --installed | grep openj` again after a `sudo apt-get purge default-jdk` to see that all 4 packages are still there. After `sudo apt-get autoremove` the 2 jdk packages are gone but the 2 jre packages are still there!

Comment: oh I should add that in the meantime I have done a `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` (which has solved my actual problem which I haven't described). So maybe that's the reason why he keeps the jre11 packages despite an autoremove? Which would be weird because why would OpenJDK8 want to have those packages. Anyway, now I have both, default-jdk and openjdk-8-jdk. I switch between the two via `sudo update-java-alternatives`.